# Database read complexity

Tags: sql, sql-server, complexity-theory

I have a relational table in SQL which relates Users with Permissions. So is in the middle of an Many to Many relationship.

The table has its proper indexes and foreign keys.

The users belongs to Groups, so I'm wondering if it will be much more efficent to keep the relation between Groups-Permissions instead of Users-Permissions, this way I will have a lot of less rows in the table, so I'm wondering how well will performance instead of the other way.

In the end my question is: how is the complexity of reading table in database?

I'm pretty sure it is "theorically" O(1) but actually something more like O(nlogn) or o(n) because it will have to index data somehow.

By the way I'm using SQL Server dbms, but I'm pretty sure the answer applies to SQL, mySQL, etc (excluding non-relational dbms like Mongo)

Comment: Too broad. You also are seriously overthinking the db side and ignoring anything outside of the db (like an in memory cache). There simply is not even a need - or sense - in doing that purely on the db side.

Comment: I'm just thinking how optimize that part, in the end of course I can use cache, but just thinking if this was optimal I wondered the complexity of reading a table

Comment: It is a bad example. I would cache for example the group-permission setup in a rights manager. Makes things a LOT easier. Also reduces a ton of data transfer to the database.

Comment: My question is actually how is the complexity of reading a table in database. I simplified the architecture for the question, the table will work for saving the analysis for permissions, I wanted to use only the relation to group-permissions, but not doing another join, so instead of asking if a user has a permission i'd ask if the group of the user has the permission, this would make a lot of less rows in the table, so I'm wondering if reducing that much of the size of the table will improve the performance, that why i was asking for the complexity in reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never know even "theoretically" what is the complexity of reading a table in a database, since every table is different then the other.

One may have 2 columns and another can have 200, one have 10 records, and another can have 100mil, one can have indexes and the other may don't and ETC.

This effects the complexity so, every case to it self.

In addition, yes, if your users are seperated into groups(and two people in the same group have the same permissions) then its more right to have the relations

GROUPS > PERMISSIONS

USERS > GROUPS

than what you did, because if you will want(and you probably will) to add or remove a group permissions, in your case it may be complicated and will need unnecessary join and resources, than just change permission of one group.

Performance prespective, again, as I said, I cant tell you